# Changing list items height based on data-attribute using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

so i need to make lis with the same data-attribute the same height, using plain javascript and no tables, however i'm struggling with this task, mainly getting lis with the same data attribute. Here's the code: https://codepen.io/benasl/pen/ooLrON?editors=1010

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <ul>
      <li class="item" data-item="1"><p>testt tte sttest testtesttesttes ttesttes ttesttesttest</p></li>
      <li class="item" data-item="2"><p>test</p></li>
      <li class="item" data-item="3"><p>test aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa a aaaa aaaaaaaa</p></li>
      <li class="item" data-item="4"><p>test</p></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <ul>
      <li class="item" data-item="1"><p>testt tte sttest testtesttesttes ttesttasdsadasd es ttesttesttestas asdasdasdsad asdasdasd</p></li>
      <li class="item" data-item="2"><p>test</p></li>
      <li class="item" data-item="3"><p>test aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa a aaaa aaaaaaaa</p></li>
      <li class="item" data-item="4"><p>test</p></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <ul>
      <li class="item" data-item="1"><p>testt tte sttest testtesttesttes ttesttes ttesttesttest</p></li>
      <li class="item" data-item="2"><p>test</p></li>
      <li class="item" data-item="3"><p>test aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa a aaaa aaaaaaaa</p></li>
      <li class="item" data-item="4"><p>test</p></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the attribute selector in CSS. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) is a simple guide.

You may want something like:

```
li[data-item="1"] {
  height: 5px;
}
```

Comment: What i need is for example if one of the lis with data-item(1) has a bigger height, to make every li with that data-attribute have the same height as the biggest one. Also, the lis will be dynamically generated.